# Displaying a dropdown based on selection of another

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I've got 2 dropdowns and I want to display items in the second dropdown only if I select a specific item from the first dropdown.

```
            <base-select
            class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 mb10"
            name="countries"
            :options="countryOptions"
            :selected="shipping.country"
            :placeholder="$t('Country *')"
            :validations="[
              {
                condition: $v.shipping.country.$error && !$v.shipping.country.required,
                text: $t('Field is required')
              }
            ]"
            v-model="shipping.country"
            autocomplete="country-name"
            @blur="$v.shipping.country.$touch()"
            @change.native="$v.shipping.country.$touch(); changeCountry();"
          />

          <base-select
            class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 mb10"
            name="rocities"
            :options="rocitiesOptions"
            :selected="shipping.rocities"
            :placeholder="$t('State / Province *')"
            :validations="[
              {
                condition: $v.shipping.rocities.$error && !$v.shipping.rocities.required,
                text: $t('Field is required')
              }
            ]"
            v-model="shipping.rocities"
            autocomplete="rocities-name"
            @blur="$v.shipping.rocities.$touch()"
            @change.native="$v.shipping.rocities.$touch(); changerocities();"
          />
```

Here is my code..
I am currently displaying items in both dropdowns but I can't figure out where and which condition do I have to write to display items in the second dropdown in the specified situation.

I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Can you just add a v-if to the second select box? Also, https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: You're using ```v-model``` but you also have a handler on ```@change```, what does ```changeCountry``` do? Do you want to disabled or hide the second select until the user selects a country?

Comment: I want second select to be disabled until the user selects a country
`
changeCountry () {
      this.$bus.$emit('checkout-before-shippingMethods', this.shipping.country)
    }
`

Comment: @AlexMA can you give example of the entire 'v-if'?

Comment: I don't know how ```base-select``` is implemented, but it could have a prop called ```disabled``` and you can use it in your rocities element by passing ```:disabled="shipping.country"```. This is the simplest way of enabling/disabling an element based on another's value.